# problem in installing Epson Scanner in Lubuntu 15.10 (64bits)

Tags: lubuntu, 64-bit, scanner, epson

I used my Epson scanner L210 on Lubuntu 15.04 32bits, but after changing to Lubuntu 15.10 64bits, 
I'm not able to use it again!
I downloaded driver from here:
[Epson L210 scanner driver](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html)

I followed these instruction :
[How to install Scanner on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install the drivers and follow the instructions you mentioned.

In the file  `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`,  uncomment the backend `epkowa` (in my case it wasn't on the list, so I had to include it).

Comment the backend `epson2` (by prepending `#`). It seems to be in conflict with `epkowa`.

Proceed with the instructions by editing the file `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf`.

Comment: I am having the same problem with EPSON scanner in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried these steps but I am not being able to save it as it appears as read only. Any suggestions?